# Are these ring notations equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The following are defined [here](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/slides-porto-rings.pdf)$$R=\mathbb{Z[X]}/(X^n+1)\\R_{q'}=R/qR$$ and $$R_{q''}=\mathbb{Z_q[X]}/(X^n+1)$$
$R$ is called a cyclotomic ring (maybe someone could explain why is called like this) and q is a integer modulus.
$\\$
My question is:

Are $R_{q'}$ and $R_{q''}$ the same?

Comment: Well, with regards to "cyclotomic", it looks like you're confusing two separate slides. "Cyclotomic" refers to the polynomial $x^n-1$ (which would be the same as $x^n+1$ in rings with characteristic $2$.)

Comment: When I looked at the slides it seems to me that the quotient by $x^n+1$ is mentioned out the front, but that the rest of the paper deals with quotients by $x^n-1$. This is the standard setting for cyclic linear codes.

Comment: Ok, got it @rschwieb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are asking whether $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^n+1,q)$ is the same as $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)[X]/(X^n+1)$. The answer is yes.

Comment: Great, I knew it! :D